# ¿Como puedo bloquear la edición de archivos js desde el explorador en un proyecto laravel?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel-5, seguridad

Tengo un proyecto de laravel montado en un servidor, el cual tiene los archivos js dentro de la carpeta public. Usando las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador, puedo ver el código fuente de los archivos js utilizados. El problema que tengo es que desde estas herramientas puedo editar esos archivos, guardar los cambios (CTRL+S) y sin recargar la página, esos cambios se ejecutan, por ejemplo teniendo el código original siguiente:

```
$("#botonEnvio").click(function()
    alert("Se ha presionado el boton de envio");
);
```

desde las herramientas de desarrollo, busco este archivo y le agrego una línea más como sigue:

```
$("#botonEnvio").click(function()
    alert("Se ha presionado el boton de envio");
    alert("mensaje de codigo editado");
);
```

con esto al presionar el botón con id "botonEnvio", me muestra las dos alertas (original y la agregada por navegador), siendo que por seguridad solo debería mostrarme la primer alerta.

¿Existe alguna forma de poder bloquear este tipo de edición, alguna configuración o agregar algún tipo de seguridad?.

De antemano muchas gracias por sus comentarios.

Saludos

Comment: No, no existe forma de bloquear ese  tipo de edición porque se realiza a través de las herramientas de desarrollador. Las herramientas de desarrollador exponen el sitio entero al usuario. No es fallo de seguridad, esas herramientas sirven exclusivamente para ese tipo de acciones. Toda validación debería hacerce en el lado servidor (_backend_). Si tus validaciones están únicamente en el lado cliente (_frontend_) entonces sí es problema de seguridad y debes re-plantearte toda la arquitectura de tu proyecto. _"Jamás confíes en la entrada del usuario"_.

Comment: No te sorprenda que el usuario ni siquiera use el sitio para rellenar tus formularios. Estos pueden automatizarse programáticamente, así que deberías dejar atrás la paranoía y enfocar tus recursos a acciones más apremiantes (colocar captchas, crear una REST api con algún rate-limit, aplicar rate-limits sin exponer la API interna, etc)